# How to calculate the length of a curve between two points

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, arc-length

> Calculate the length of the  curve: $y = \frac{1}{x}$ between points $(1,1)$ and $(2, \frac{1}{2})$.

What I tried:
$$ \int_a^b\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2} dt$$
$$r(t) =(t,1/t) $$
$$\int_1^2\sqrt{(1)^2+\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)^2}\,dt$$
$$\int_1^2\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t^{4}}}\,dt$$

However, if my procedure to here is correct (I am not sure), then I wanted to solve this integral and that would give me my solution.

$$\int_1^2 \frac{1}{t^2} \sqrt{t^4+1}\,dt$$
However, I do not know what substitution to make in this integral for this to work.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a calculator? I think this can only be (feasibly) done numerically.

Comment: @JakeBrown No I cannot. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere in the process, and the integral is not as hard as I written.

Comment: Your setup is correct for the given question, it should be $\int_1^2\sqrt{1+t^{-4}}\,dt$, and even Wolfram doesn't seem to have a non-numerical solution.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2Bt%5E4%29%5E%281%2F2%29+%2Ft%5E2%2C+%7Bt%2C1%2C2%7D uses a hypergeometric function

Comment: You can check [this page](https://socratic.org/answers/636595), maybe it can help.

Comment: My guess is that the question is asking you to find a setup to calculate it rather than directly calculate it, because all of the solutions in the comments seem to require a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation of the integral is perfectly fine, but to actually evaluate it requires elliptic integrals. We can rewrite the integral as
$$\int_1^2\frac{t^2+1/t^2}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}\,dt$$
Then using the formulas on page 7 of my [Elliptic Integrals and Functions](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Dounreay/-/blob/master/misc/elliptic-integrals-and-functions.pdf) monograph transforms this into
$$\int_{F(\pi/2,1/2)}^{F(2\tan^{-1}2,1/2)}\left(\frac2{\operatorname{sn}^2(u,1/2)}-1\right)\,du$$
where Mathematica convention is used. Page 8 of the monograph (the $B_k$ part) reduces this to $f(2)-f(1)$ where
$$f(p)=F(2\tan^{-1}p,1/2)-2E(2\tan^{-1}p,1/2)+\frac{(p^2-1)\sqrt{p^4+1}}{p(p^2+1)}$$
The addition formulae on page 4 reduce this even further, to
$$F\left(\sin^{-1}\frac3{\sqrt{17}},\frac12\right)-2E\left(\sin^{-1}\frac3{\sqrt{17}},\frac12\right)+\frac{15}{2\sqrt{17}}$$